# WordPress - Add submit button to admin toolbar

Tags: wordpress, function

I have my own function **fsww_i_add_funds_request_daily**  that I wrote to perform the addition of a profit by a user based on the role of the user. This function was created / added for one plugin that I use. I am not sending any parameters to the function. I need to call this function using the submit button which will be on the admin toolbar. The function should be implemented in the plugin as it is necessary to use its "library" (maybe I spoke badly, I'm still a beginner in WP). How and where I need these functions implement?

Function

```
function fsww_i_add_funds_request_daily() {
        
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Wallet.php');
        
        global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}fswcwallet ORDER BY user_id ASC");
        
        if($query) {
                
                foreach($query as $user) 
                {
                    $user_id = $user->user_id;
                    $dailyProvision = 0;
                    
                    if($user_id != 0) 
                    {
                        $balance        = fsww_price(Wallet::get_balance($user_id));
                        $last_deposit   = fswcw_format_date(Wallet::get_last_deposit($user_id));
                        $status         = Wallet::get_status($user_id);
                        
                        $username       = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
                        
                                            
                    }
                }
        }        
}

function fb_add_admin_bar_profit() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $current_object = get_queried_object();
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(
        array( 'id' => 'addprofit',
        'title' => __('Add profit'),
        'href' => ?????)
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'fb_add_admin_bar_profit');
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create plugin `Custom Plugin` and add the below code to that plugin. and in you admin bar custom button add URL like this `home_url( '/?funds_request_daily=true' )` and check this query string `funds_request_daily` params on `init` hook.

```
<?php

    /**
     * Plugin Name:       Custom Plugin
     * Plugin URI:        https://example.com/plugins/the-basics/
     * Description:       Handle the basics with this plugin.
     * Version:           1.0.0
     * Author:            Cleemas
     * Author URI:        https://author.example.com/
     * License:           GPL v2 or later
     * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
     * Text Domain:       my-custom-plugin
     * Domain Path:       /languages
     */


    function fsww_i_add_funds_request_daily() {
            
        if( isset( $_GET['funds_request_daily'] ) && $_GET['funds_request_daily'] == 'true' ){

            require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Wallet.php');
            
            global $wpdb;
            $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}fswcwallet ORDER BY user_id ASC");
            
            if( $query ) {    

                foreach( $query as $user )  {

                    $user_id = $user->user_id;
                    $dailyProvision = 0;
                    
                    if($user_id != 0)  {
                        $balance      = fsww_price(Wallet::get_balance($user_id));
                        $last_deposit = fswcw_format_date(Wallet::get_last_deposit($user_id));
                        $status       = Wallet::get_status($user_id);
                        $username     = get_user_by('id', $user_id);      
                    }

                }

            }        

        }

    }

    add_action( 'init', 'fsww_i_add_funds_request_daily', 10, 1 );

    function fb_add_admin_bar_profit() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        $current_object = get_queried_object();
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(
            array( 
                'id' => 'addprofit',
                'title' => __('Add profit'),
                'href' => home_url( '/?funds_request_daily=true' )
            )
        );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'fb_add_admin_bar_profit');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. when I added the given code in the plugin that I use on the path in the plugin: FS_WooCommerce_Wallet/includes/functions.php .. after clicking on the button in the admin toolbar I get an error message: There has been a critical error on this website. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when I modified 'href' => home_url ('/wp-content/plugins/FS_WooCommerce_Wallet/includes/functions.php/?funds_request_daily=true'. It started working. Thanks.